# Overriding module-checkout > view > frontend > layout > default.xml

Tags: magento2, layout, knockoutjs

I am trying to move the minicart from the header into the header panel. To do this, I need to update the `default.xml` file located here:

`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

I believe this is done by copying this file to my local theme directory, here:

`app/design/frontend/myvendor/mytheme/Magento_Checkout/layout/default.xml`

However, when making this copy (and no code changes), I am seeing errors related to knockoutjs and the minicart modal no longer renders correctly when the cart is clicked.

That said, changes to this overriding file do correctly render, e.g. renaming the reference container to `header.panel` does move the minicart icon.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cracked it. Since I was overriding a base layout file (not a parent theme file?), I needed to place my file inside

`layout/override/base/default.xml`

Comment: 100% right solution

Comment: This worked for me after many hours of frustration. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please clarify where you placed the file?

layout/override/base/default.xml

app/design/frontend/myvendor/mytheme/Magento_Checkout/layout/override/base/default.xml

app/design/frontend/myvendor/mytheme/layout/override/base/default.xml

Thank you

Comment: I no longer have the project in front of me, but feel free to try both locations.